# Xamarin: FirebaseInstallations what to provide in AddOnSuccessListener

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android

I'm following [this arcticle](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/developer/mobile-apps/notification-hubs-backend-service-xamarin-forms#handle-push-notifications-for-android). Check step 12.

12. In the same method, conditionally call GetInstanceId on the FirebaseApp instance, right after the call to Bootstrap.Begin, adding MainActivity as the IOnSuccessListener.

```
if (DeviceInstallationService.NotificationsSupported)
{
    FirebaseInstanceId.GetInstance(Firebase.FirebaseApp.Instance)
        .GetInstanceId()
        .AddOnSuccessListener(this);
}
```

But `FirebaseInstanceId` is deprecated. Instead I need to write similar code, something like:

```
if (DeviceInstallationService.NotificationsSupported)
{ 
    FirebaseInstallations.GetInstance(Firebase.FirebaseApp.Instance)
        .GetId()
        .AddOnSuccessListener(???);
}
```

What should I provide to `AddOnSuccessListener`?

Comment: What exactly is the problem here, can you clarify? Doesn't the `AddOnSuccessListener()` of the second example also take an `IOnSuccessListener` as an argument? If your MainActivity implements that interface, why can't you use `this` again?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured it out.
You need to make `MainActivity` implement `IOnSuccessListener`, like this:

```
public class MainActivity : global::Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android.FormsAppCompatActivity, IOnSuccessListener
```

Also you need update code like this:

```
if (DeviceInstallationService.NotificationsSupported)
{            
     FirebaseMessaging.Instance
                    .GetToken()
                    .AddOnSuccessListener(this);
}
```

And you need to update `OnSuccess` like this:

```
public void OnSuccess(Java.Lang.Object result)
{ 
    DeviceInstallationService.Token = result.ToString();
}
```